# Generalization of "symmetric positive definite" to higher dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, positive-definite, multilinear-algebra

Suppose I have a positive-definite function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^1$.

Then the Hessian $\nabla^2 f$ is symmetric positive definite and I can write $\nabla^2 f=QQ^T$ for some real-valued matrix $Q$. It allows me to write $q'Hq$ as $\|u\|^2$ with $u=Q^Tq$

Is there an analogue to "symmetric positive definite" for $\nabla^4 f$ and a corresponding decomposition? IE, something that would allow me to evaluate the quartic form efficiently, for instance, as $\|u\|^4$

Comment: tangentially related: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060467/invariant-subsets-of-orthogonal-representation-of-symmetric-3-tensor) (And in general $\nabla^2 f$ is not positive definite)

Comment: @ArcticChar good point, I've been looking at loss functions like cross-entropy loss for so long I forgot other functions exist. Edited to specify "positive definite" function

Comment: This reminds me of [a previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3944363/8157), which received an interesting comment of Rodrigo de Azevedo. P.S. Interestingly I wrote this comment simultaneously with Rodrigo.

Comment: A $p$-linear symmetric form is called positive definite if $\varphi(x^{(p)}) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $(x_1, \ldots, x_p) \mapsto \varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_p)$ is linear in each entry.

Comment: @WilliamM. What's $x^{(p)}$?

Comment: @ArcticChar $x^{(p)}$ is short-hand for $(x, \ldots, x) \in \mathrm{V}^p,$ and $\mathrm{V}^p$ is the vector space where $x$ lies.